# Why did Singapore Airlines decide to discontinue the longest non-stop flight in the world?

Tags: singapore, jfk, singapore-airlines

As many of us know, the longest non-stop commercial flight in the world operated between Singapore and New York with flight number SQ21. This flight was operated by Airbus A340-500 and the flight duration was about 19 hours. Why did Singapore Airlines decide to cancel this route?

Comment: for cost reasons, of course.

Comment: Because it was the longest flight in the world. If running long flights was a no brainer (technically and economically) many people would run flights as long or longer than this one.

Comment: Some discussion on this here: http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-17/singapore-air-yearns-to-reclaim-title-of-world-s-longest-flight
A big potential issue is fuel: You need to burn a lot of fuel at take off to get the fuel for the next 19 hours up in the air.

Comment: @Hilmar: And as a followup to your comment, see [Why don't airliners use in-air refueling systems?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/why-dont-airliners-use-in-air-refueling-systems).

Comment: Really? I thought it would be longer by now. In 2012, I took a 19h26m flight from Toronto to Hong Kong. It was the longest flight at the time but I thought there would be some 20-21 hours ones by now.

Comment: The airline's job is to return a profit to its shareholders, not to break records. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was fairly widely reported that fuel costs made the flights uneconomical.  The maintenance of the A340-500s SIA retained specifically for the flight also contributed, as they only had five A340-500s.

Sample quotes:

> It is widely known in the industry that SIA’s A340-500 non-stop
>   flights to the U.S. are unprofitable, because of the four-engined
>   aircraft’s higher fuel burn. Some SIA executives were also questioning
>   why the carrier was going to the trouble of maintaining such a small
>   fleet of A340s.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20130324000529/http://www.aviationweek.com/Article.aspx?id=/article-xml/awx_10_24_2012_p0-510102.xml)

> Snyder and most other experts suspect the airline got tired of dealing
>   with poor profit margins on the fuel-guzzling four-engine Airbus A340.
>   "They do use a ton of fuel, and that's always painful," says Snyder.

[Source](http://www.cnn.com/2013/10/19/travel/worlds-longest-flight/)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add that this flight was revived by SIA in October 2018 but with the more fuel-efficient A350 (previously the A340 was used).

[SingaporeAir.com](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/be/media-centre/press-release/article/?q=en_UK/2018/October-December/ne3418-181012)

> The first new non-stop flight between Singapore and New York departed Changi International Airport on 11 October 2018 at 2337hrs (SIN time) and arrived at Newark Liberty International Airport a day later, at 0529hrs (US Eastern time). The flight duration was 17 hours 52 minutes.

Nikkei Asia ([2018](https://asia.nikkei.com/Business/Companies/Singapore-Airlines-races-oil-price-with-world-s-longest-flight)):

> This time, Singapore's flag carrier counts on an ultralong-range version of the fuel-efficient Airbus A350-900 jet to cut fuel costs ...

> Singapore Airlines debuted a direct flight to New York in 2004, but surging crude oil prices forced the carrier to scrap the route five years ago [2013]. The four-engine Airbus 340-500 consumed too much fuel and crude prices were running high, at above $100 per barrel. Meanwhile, the economic slump that followed the global financial crisis stunted demand for business travel.

> Now, with the world economy in better shape, one airline after another in the Asia-Pacific region is adding new long-haul flights.