# Longest Possible Flight

Tags: air-travel, long-haul

With the current technology in 2016, on which plane can I travel the furthest distance without stopping to refuel?

Please answer with information on the distance, plane type, and approximate flight time.

Comment: See Wiki's [Non-stop flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stop_flight). Also, we have an existing question [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/what-is-the-longest-passenger-flight-with-a-flight-number-in-the-world/10333#10333) which should be updated and a related question [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56485/why-did-singapore-airlines-decide-to-discontinue-the-longest-non-stop-flight-in).

Comment: Some more parameters would help. The obvious winners would be something like the [Rutan Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Voyager) (perhaps [Solar Impulse 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Impulse#Operational_history_2) in the future), see also [Flight endurance record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_endurance_record). But you're unlikely to be able to fly on one. Or do you want a commercially available flight? Modern commercial aircraft can fly far farther than their normal range if equipped with extra fuel tanks and carry minimal payload, but this isn't profitable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about aviation, I think it is better to ask it on [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for link @mkennedy - I've added an answer for 2016.